# R divide column into two classes

Tags: r, class

I have the attached data set [ts.dilute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZftID.png)

I want to divide the reaction column into two classes: "from 8 to 12" and "from 12 to 18". I want to call these "low" and "high" respectively. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time, use `head(ts.dilute, 5)` and copy/paste the result here instead of the screenshot.

You could use `cut()` to create a 2 level factor, which would make anything outside of your ranges an `NA`.

```
ts.dilute$class <- cut(ts.dilute$reaction, breaks = c(8,12,18), labels =c("low","high"), include.lowest = TRUE)
```

or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)  

ts.dilute <- ts.dilute %>%
     mutate(class = cut(reaction, breaks = c(8,12,18), labels =c("low","high"), include.lowest = TRUE)
```